# Build a PDF document using Cognito Forms and sending it to Sharepoint List as an attachment

Tags: cognito-forms, sharepoint

Is it possible to build a PDF document using Cognito Forms and push that document to SharePoint List as an attachment? I know that you can send that PDF document to email but not sure if it is possible to send it to a Sharepoint list.

Answer (score 1):

While you can send custom generated documents to most cloud services from [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) using [Zapier](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/68/data-integration/zapier), our [SharePoint Integration](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/64/data-integration/microsoft-sharepoint) feature does not currently support adding generated documents as attachments to lists.

However, this is a feature that we are considering and have placed on our public Idea Board:
https://trello.com/c/Xuz1ZLy7/243-allow-generated-documents-to-be-added-as-attachments-to-sharepoint-lists